# Angular http post returning a 403 error on server only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, post, http-status-code-403

I have a simple HTTP post call in an angular controller that works fine when I run it on my local host, but gets a 403 error when it is deployed to a stage server. More specifically it only gets the 403 error on Chrome, it works fine on IE and FireFox.

Here is the JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'], function($locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
});

app.controller('ClearFilesController', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', '$filter','$window','$location',function($rootScope, $timeout, $scope, $http, $uibModal, $filter,$window,$location) {

$scope.message = "Clear Test Files";
$scope.statusMessage = "Click the button to delete test files in the 'Automation Testing' Collection";

$scope.deleteFiles = function(){
    $scope.statusMessage = "Clearing files...";
    $http.post('/clearFiles')
        .then(function(response){
            var status = response.status;
            if('200'!=status) {
                $scope.statusMessage = "Clearing of files failed.";
            } else {
                $scope.statusMessage = "Successfully cleared files.";
            }
        });

};

}]);
```

Here is the error from the dev tools on Chrome: angular.js:11630 POST https://sample-stageserver.com/clearFiles/ 403 (Forbidden)

What would be a possible reason why I am only getting this error in Chrome?

Comment: Check the Network tab in F12 tools to see what is different (headers, etc...)

Comment: I tried that and didn't really see any differences other than the status code obviously. Other than that there really wasn't much different

Comment: Try http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: The only difference I have found is Chrome has an origin and a host in the headers...Host:sample-stageserver.com
Origin:https://sample-stageserver.com but FireFox and IE only have host. Could that be causing it?

Comment: If it's the only difference, then I'd say it must be causing it.  https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Origin  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: Any resolution on this? I've been getting the same thing.  In my case I can see that the response from my API is that the CSRF token is missing.  But it's working in FF, and even if I take what is sent from chrome, caught by postman, and send the request from postman, it works.  Very strange.  You solve it?

Comment: @shanemgrey no I haven't been able to solve the issue yet. With little to no feedback on the error itself, I haven't been able to identify the root cause. Since it wasn't critical for me to be able to use Chrome for the call I moved passed it and simply use FF for this; although it does still bother me that Chrome doesn't work.

Comment: It's still a big problem for me because it essentially makes chrome unusable for my application. Chrome users can't POST anything. I'll reply back here when I solve it.

Comment: Oh yeah, that would definitely be a larger problem. I just needed it to run an automation script, so it was fine to just use FF. Thanks, hopefully you get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can add comment - so u can try postman for the testing your problem.
And try use basic $http like as an example - [Angular $http doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (not the shorthand).